# Mocking data using Moq and xunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am new to unit testing and by following so many articles, I am able to write below unit test but it is not working since there is no relationship between main class and factory class. How to solve this problem? Is it possible to write unit test without changing the structure of my class.

My Class:

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
        {    
            public ServiceClientManager<IScan> scan;

            public SomeClass(Action<String> logMessages)
            {
                this.logMessage = logMessages;
            }

            public void Process(string a, string b, string c)
            {
            if (this.Scan == null)
            {
               ConnectToScan();                   
            }

            if (status)
            {
                Scan.Proxy.MethodScan(a, b, c);
            }
        }
} 



public bool ConnectToScan()
        {
            this.Scan = null;
                NetTcpBinding netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
                netTcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
                netTcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                netTcpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                netTcpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                netTcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                barcodeScanner = new ServiceClientManager<IScan>(netTcpBinding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost/XXXX"));
                return true;
        }
```

Here, ConnectToScan() will establish the connection to the service and I am using it inside Process method to pass parameters to that service. In order to write unit test for this method, I am trying to mock the service "IScan" and assert that service method is called atleast once.

My unit test:

```
  private Action<string> _logMessage = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);

       [Fact]
    public void MethodTest()
    {
        var factoryScanMoq = new Mock<IScan>();
        factoryScanMoq.Setup(x => x.MethodScan("test", "S000", "test2"))
        .Returns(null);

        var mockService = new ServiceClientManager<IScan>(factoryBarcodeScanMoq.Object);

        classObj.process("test", "S000", "test2"); // FactoryScanMoq is not passed here

        classObj.Scan = mockService;

        factoryScanMoq.Verify(x => x.MethodScan("test", "S000", "test2"), Times.Once);
    }
```

I Know there is no relation between factory Mock and SomeClass but I am not sure how to create a relation since I cannot pass FactoryMoq to SomeClass as a constructor argument.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there is no relation between factory and another class, do you think it's possible to write two tests and test them separately?

Comment: It's easier to solve concrete isolated problems. Currently, it's difficult to isolate a problem in your case, taking into consideration “what ifs” and “it mays”. Let's go with the first question: can you test you class without factory? If no, then why?

Comment: I think No because my method is  just passing values to external API and not receiving any response. SO, if I remove factory, what can I test?

Comment: My thinking might be wrong. Can you please send me some example if there is a way to test my method without factory. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Is the factory used inside the class then? I mean, not in the test, but in real code, is it instantiated inside `Process` method? Inside the `if (this.Scan == null)`, correct?

Comment: yes. It is used inside

Comment: Could you then add info about how it is instantiated inside? And why you can't pass the factory in the constructor?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add complete details in the post. I have added some info about instantiation now. Will this info helps?

Comment: That's great! Also, can you please add info that the problem is that the factory is instantiated inside the class and you can't pass an instance inside? Emphasizing on that the factory is instantiated inside. It is obvious from code, but isn't mentioned in the text. And that's the main issue here. And everything else is good.